# Obtain elements from a list which are not defined in table column

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

The challenge here is that I have read only right on the database. I cannot create an auxiliary/temporary table to insert the list of elements to make the comparison.

I have a list of elements in an excel, about 300. I need to compare this list of elements (strings) with a column of a table.

But I really need the elements of the list where are not defined in de column table.

I know how to obtain the element defined in column table and in elements' list.

```
select table.code from table
where table.code in (ele1, ele2, ...);
```

But I have no idea how to obtain elements in list not defined in the table.

If i can create a temporary table, i will use join to do this job so easily.

Comment: Nope @Sal the task as I understod it to get the codes from the *excel* list `MINUS` the code from the table

Comment: WHere are you going to run this SQL, is it from a front end or a PL/SQL code? You can try creating a string that you can use it as a WHERE clause in a dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possible solution to workaround your missing `create table` rights is to use *collections*.

You must initialize the collection with your excel codes.

That it is a trivial task to select the codes from the collection `minus` the codes from your table.

The following **PL/SQL** snippes illustrates it

```
declare
  my_excel_codes SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
begin
  my_excel_codes := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('A','B','C');
  
  for cur in (
    select COLUMN_VALUE code from  TABLE( my_excel_codes ) 
      minus
    select code from tab)  
  loop
     dbms_output.put_line(cur.code );
  end loop;
end;
/
```

This is the **SQL Solution** based on the same principle

```
select column_value from table (
SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST(
'A','B','C' -- your CSV code list here
))
MINUS
select code from tab;
```

It works with up to 999 codes in the CSV list. Up 1000 elements you get `ORA-00939: too many arguments for function` (tested in 18.4 XE)

Answer (score 1):

You could convert the excel to a CTE using a text editor that (eg sublime)

Example. Take an excel file with 4 rows red, yellow, green, white

and compare that against to table of colors:

```
drop table colors;
create table colors (color VARCHAR2(10));
INSERT INTO colors (color) VALUES ('red'); 
INSERT INTO colors (color) VALUES ('blue'); 
INSERT INTO colors (color) VALUES ('white'); 

-- this is the excel file values re-written as a CTE
WITH my_excel_colors(color) AS
(SELECT 'red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'yellow' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'green' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
 SELECT 'white' FROM DUAL
) 
SELECT color FROM my_excel_colors 
MINUS 
SELECT color FROM colors;
```

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, for a small dataset, I would just do this in Excel.

Let's say your existing Excel strings are in column A.

1. Run `select table.code from table`
2. Copy/paste the resultset into Excel in column B
3. In column C, put equation `=COUNTIF($B:$B, $A1)` in C1 and copy down to the whole column
4. Filter on rows where column C is 0

Comment: Yes, that's a solution i've used for little list. Thanks for the idea.