# Dynamic where in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to dynamically build an IN in a where clause and it will not work with multiple values. It does work when I put in a single value. I test the output with dmbs_output and it appears correct. Logic is inside of a procedure. Any help is welcome.

```
xq:=q'#select '('||q'[']'||REPLACE(UPPER(:pc),',',q'[',']')||q'[']'||')'  from dual#';
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE xq BULK COLLECT
        INTO qu 
       using pclient_code;
pclient_code2 := qu(1);
```

Then much later in the procedure

```
where
acv.client_code in case when pclient_code='*' then acv.client_code else pclient_code2 end
```

The interface is

````
(pclient_code IN VARCHAR2,pclient_loc IN VARCHAR2,plob IN VARCHAR2,pclient_sube IN VARCHAR2, c_data IN OUT APP_NADS.PKG_STAND_SUBRO_ITD_ALL.type_stand_subro_itd_ALL) ```
````

Comment: You'll have to provide some details about your interfaces to get a meaningfull advice other than that your implementation does not work. Are you looking for something similar to this [setup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66353380/4808122)?

Comment: What information would be helpful? I am fairly new to PL SQL.

Comment: I guess the interface of your procedure is crutial, you are passing somehow a collection of ID to be selected in the `IN`  condition. BTW pretty frequently a topic on this site... Try search as well.

Comment: It is``` (pclient_code IN VARCHAR2,pclient_loc IN VARCHAR2,plob IN VARCHAR2,pclient_sube IN VARCHAR2, c_data IN OUT APP_NADS.PKG_STAND_SUBRO_ITD_ALL.type_stand_subro_itd_ALL)```

Comment: When adding requested information **Update the Question**; do not just add another comment. Comments are much more difficult to follow - essentially unformulated, esp code. But also unseen by later potential responders. 3-4 comments I will look at, 8-10 less likely.

Comment: I appreciate the advice, I have updated the question

Comment: *What information would be helpful?* Imagine you are trying to answer this question. How do you run it yourself to test it and develop a working version?